# Axios AJAX call nulls parameter

Tags: ajax, vue.js, axios

I use Vuejs to create my frontend for my project.

At the creation of one component ('TimeCapsy.vue'), I make an AJAX call to my backend like this:

```
created: function () {
        if (verify.verify_login()) {
          let token = this.$cookies.get('jwt_us_cas');
          let params = {'jwt': token};
          console.log(params);
          axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: dev.HOST+'getuserinfoobject',
            params: queryString.stringify(params)
          })
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response.data)
            })
        }
      }
```

As you can see I use the

```
this.$cookies.get('jwt_us_cas');
```

to get the a json web token, that I set on the client at the login.

I use the `queryString` Library to stringify my parameters for my request.

I also tried it without the `queryString.stringify(params)` call, but I get the same error, e.g. the parameter still turns into null.

When I look at the console log, where I check the params variable, I get this output:

{jwt: "*my token comes here*"}

So I can see, that it gets the correct value from the cookie.

But when I check the answer from my backend (PHP), I get this error:

```
Undefined index: jwt in <b>D:\casb\public\index.php</b> on line <b>52</b>
```

Of course I know that it means, that `jwt` is null, but I can't understand why.

As I said, right before I make the call I check the params and it shows the token.

I checked the endpoint with Postman and the token as the `jwt` parameter and it returned a successfull call with the correct answer.

A correct answer is basically just a nested object with some information in it.

My PHP endpoint is pretty basic too:

```
Router::add('/getuserinfoobject', function () {
    $response['response'] = User::getUserInfoObject($_POST['jwt']);
    echo json_encode($response);
}, 'post');
```

So I guess that right before or in my call it nulls my parameter. But I can't understand how, since I make a lot of requests and never had this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From axios docs

> *`params` are the URL parameters to be sent with the request*

Which means, you should get the value with PHP `$_GET`.

Or `$_REQUEST` (which stores both `$_GET`, `$_POST`. Also `$_COOKIE`).

The other hand, you can use `data` key as docs says

> *`data` is the data to be sent as the request body*
>
> *Only applicable for request methods `PUT`, `POST`, and `PATCH`*

So the value would be available in `$_POST`

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: dev.HOST+'getuserinfoobject',
  data: {
     jwt: token
  }
})
```